# Pandas/Python, if statement for df.duplicated

Tags: python, pandas

have a simple code that finds duplicate rows and prints them out if any.
It works fine without the IF statement, so it always prints:

```
duplicated rows in the sheet : 
 Empty DataFrame
Columns: [IP,MAC,DNS,TEST,TEST2]
Index: []
```

I would like to add an IF statement to print out results only if the duplicated values have been found.
Otherwise print "no duplicates"

```
import pandas as pd 



    df = pd.DataFrame(values,columns=['IP','MAC','DNS','TEST','TEST2'])

                print('\n you are working on this data: \n',df)

                if df.duplicated()==True:
                    duplicatedRows  = df[df.duplicated()]
                    print('\n duplicated rows in the sheet : \n',duplicatedRows)
                    x= input('\n Please type "y" to continue or "x" exit\n').lower()
                else:
                    print ('no duplicates')
```

Comment: hint: check the results of `df.duplicated()`. note how you're testing it for a precise boolean `True`, but then expecting the same method to return something else in the following line. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataFrame has duplicated method which you can use to get duplicate rows like below

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(3, (10,3)), columns = "A B C".split())
duplicated = df[df.duplicated()]
if len(duplicated):
    print(duplicated)
else:
    print("no duplicates")
```